# Angular-ui-routing, conditionally block all routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is the run block of my angular application.
When user has not setup his account i.e User has not configured his currency and timezone in account, I want the User to be redirected to AccountSetup page, and all other routes to be blocked.

This works always except when the user start at worng url right in his first interaction, as in if the user opens a new tab and directly puts in the url "www.host.com/channel1", it runs into a infinite digest cycle which is terminated after 10 cycles.
I do not get what is wrong here, it keeps switching between the state channel1State and accountSetup state.

```
.run(["$stateParams","$rootScope","$state","$location", function($stateParams,$rootScope,$state,$location) {
$rootScope.$state = $state;
$rootScope.stateParams = $stateParams;
$rootScope.plan = myPlan;
// Edit below line when adding more channels
$rootScope.channels = myPlan.channel1 || myPlan.channel2;
$rootScope.timezone = timezone;
$rootScope.currency_type = currency_type
// this gets triggered whenever a user is not authorized
// to visit a url through out the application.
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event){
  $state.go('defaultState');
})
// this gets triggered on reload
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  // captures the state for the first reload
  debugger
  console.log("Moving to: ", toState.name)
  if (toState.name === 'rootpath'){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($rootScope.timezone && $rootScope.currency_type){
      if(myPlan.channel1)
        $state.go('channel1State');  // redirect to campaign path
      else
        $state.go('channel2State');  // redirect to segment path
    }
    else{
      $state.go('accountSetup'); //redirect to account setup page
    }
  }
  else if((!$rootScope.timezone || !$rootScope.currency_type) && toState.name != 'accountSetup'){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('accountSetup'); //redirect to account setup page
    }
})
}])
```

Comment: Is the problem triggered when the user goes to a state that exists but he shouldn't get to, or when he goes to a non-existant state.  (Is "www.host.com/channel1" a valid URL for your application?)

Comment: the problem triggered when the user goes to a state that exists but he shouldn't get to.  
Also this is triggered only if the users tries to access url in a new tab, and not if the user is clicking link in an already opened tab.

Comment: "www.host.com/channel1" yes this is a valid url

Comment: Maybe related:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1158

Comment: fixed :)  
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/898 suggets window.location as a workround.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little hard to read, but it looks like the last else-if is probably preventing it.

```
  if (toState.name === 'rootpath'){
            ...
  }
  else if((!$rootScope.timezone || !$rootScope.currency_type) && toState.name != 'accountSetup'){
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('accountSetup'); //redirect to account setup page
  }
```

When it redirects to state 'accountSetup', I don't think there's an IF statement that would let it in.  Since 'accountSetup' !== 'rootPath' it will bypass the first IF block.  And then the second is only run if toState.name != 'accountSetup'.  When it is === 'accountSetup' it is ignored.

I haven't tried this code but it might be closer to what you're actually trying to achieve:

```
.run(["$stateParams","$rootScope","$state","$location", function($stateParams,$rootScope,$state,$location) {
$rootScope.$state = $state;
$rootScope.stateParams = $stateParams;
$rootScope.plan = myPlan;
// Edit below line when adding more channels
$rootScope.channels = myPlan.channel1 || myPlan.channel2;
$rootScope.timezone = timezone;
$rootScope.currency_type = currency_type
// this gets triggered whenever a user is not authorized
// to visit a url through out the application.
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event){
  $state.go('defaultState');
})
// this gets triggered on reload
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
  // captures the state for the first reload
  debugger
  console.log("Moving to: ", toState.name)
  if (toState.name === 'accountSetup' || !$rootScope.timezone || !$rootScope.currency_type) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('accountSetup'); //redirect to account setup page
  } else if (toState.name === 'rootpath') {
    event.preventDefault();
      if(myPlan.channel1) {
        $state.go('channel1State');  // redirect to campaign path
      } else {
        $state.go('channel2State');  // redirect to segment path
      }
  }
})
}])
```

Comment: this will give you a infinite loop  

    if (toState.name === 'accountSetup'){
      event.preventDefault()
      $state.go('accountSetup')
    }

Comment: My bad, I see 'accountSetup' was meant to fall through the blocks.

Comment: yeah, this is a weird problem since the codes works for all scenarios except one. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Can you post the code for your state provider showing how the router states are setup?